# javascript Object.assign() functionality

Tags: javascript, object, pointers, variable-assignment, assign

I'm wanting to directly update the object referred by a function argument from within the scope of that function. An example:

```
var thisObj = { "val" : "original value" }; 
function modFunc(objRef) {
    objRef = { "val" : "modified" };
    console.log(objRef);  // { "val" : "modified" }
}
console.log(thisObj);  // { "val" : "original value" };
```

I understand why this happens, and I realize that I could have used

```
    objRef.val = "modified";
```

within modFunc to perform the modification.  For reasons specific to my project though, I would like to be able to accomplish something like:

```
function modFunc(objRef) {
    objRef.self = { "val" : "modified" };  // Of course this will not work, 
    // but is there an Object property or method that allows one to access 
    // the actual memory pointer being referenced by the variable?
}
```

where I can specify that I want to directly modify thisObj to reference the new object that I instantiate within modFunc.  Is this possible?  I know there are tools like Object.assign() that I could use to do this but it's not supported universally, or library tools like bind() that I could use if I imported the library, but it just seems like there might be some native syntax that would allow me to do this and I just haven't been able to find it?..

I've spent some time looking, otherwise I try not to ask questions like this.  I also know there are other similar posts to this one, but nothing exactly like what I'm asking and I don't have the 'reputation' here to be able to respond directly to posts etc. so I didn't see an easy way to focus the discussion.  Anyway, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is, essentially, a **call-by-reference** mechanism, or the ability to explicitly create a reference to a variable.  In JavaScript, that's not possible. You can (as you note) pass around references to *objects* and use those to modify object property values (and to add and remove properties, even), but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Ok thank you, this is exactly what I was asking.  I'd just hoped there was some way to do it that's a little more straightforward than the workarounds I've been considering.  Figured I'd put it out there and see if anyone had a direct solution.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: There is an [obscure corner case](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/msg/d11c1e0674e0be28) involving the `arguments` object that allows a call-by-reference mechanism, but it's not useful here.

Comment: @Pointy - yeah, things can get pretty damn off-track there!  :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Wow, thanks for the link. Definitely some interesting reading.

Comment: @jtrick - Interesting that it exists.  I don't think there are many -- if any! -- useful exploits of it.  But it's always fun to know about these corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

This would be true assignment by reference which javascript doesn't support. It only supports the false, misunderstood kind of assignment by reference.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I guess I'll just have to work in a solution that's a little less elegant than what I'd hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

since you cant deal with references, you can simply make `objRef` a global variable, and not pass it as an arg at all. then you're updating the original object.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, although in this case I'm needing to protect the memory location from potential outside access.  I'd originally had the entire object construct encapsulated by a closure and was acting on 'thisObj' directly from within 'modFunc' (Essentially the same mechanism you're referring to).  In a different situation, your suggestion would work great though; thanks for the help.